# Android In App purchases v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm developing an application which uses in app purchases with version 3.
And I have added the app as alpha release and published the app on store.
So what I want's to know is after the app is published if I modify some code to test do i have to upload and republish the app to check for results.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need not republish app unless you want to distribute it to your testers using alpha testing link. You can directly install the apk with modified code on your device to test. Just ensure that the version code and name remains the same as the one installed on the alpha tab.